# Materializecss Autocomplete No Elements Appearing 1.0.0 No jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm not very experienced with javascript, jquery, ajax, etc. I have had some success with version 0.100.2 but I figure I would try to get the version that isn't dependent on jquery to work. I've tried exactly what is said in the documentation. Here is the entire page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);
  });


  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

These are the errors I'm getting. [image: Error]

I've seen some people talk about a problem with 1.0.0's initialization of autocomplete, but I'm not sure about all of what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

you're using the jQuery library, without importing the script file, 
it's mentioned in the getting-started example as well, 
 use `Vanilla Javascript` or `jQuery` and accordingly use the code-snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <!-- jQuery script file, this imports the jQuery library in your project -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // this options Object, can be improved to be received 
      // from your RESTful API in the future
      var options = {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      };

      $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({ data: options });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without jQuery?